# Is the mac app store required?

Tags: windows, macos, app-store, publish

If I make an application for Mac OS X am I required to put it on the Mac app store or can I distribute it, on my website, for free?

And what about Windows?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can distribute it however you'd like. It does not need to be in the Mac App store. Same thing for Windows.

Answer (score 3):

No there is no such requirement you are free to distribute your program however you want.

You **may** wish to use the App store as a method of distribution, but to do that you have to conform to various apple requirements.

I'm not sure what the equivalent would be for Windows, but again, there is no such requirement. Think of the millions of independent apps that have no affiliation to any centralized store, I would say the majority still fall in this category.

2018 Update - With increasing security concerns, and a desire to replicate the success of the iOS App Store, Apple have been making it harder and harder to run apps from outside the store. You can get digital certificates, and become a trusted developer, but it’s clear the future is the AppStore or broke if you want users to be able to easily run your app. Note that it remains, and likely always will, very possible to install and run any unauthorised app with a simple trip to settings, it’s just that’s clearly a big deterrent for many users, as it should be.

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to distribute it over the Mac App Store right now but that might change with the next OS X, make sure to check this out: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html