# Is it possible to distribute signed mac apps (with a free dev account) without the mac app store?

Tags: code-signing, software-distribution, mac-app-store

This might seem a silly question, but I come from iOS development which is a bit more restricted as we (all) know.

My question is partially answered here:
[Is the mac app store required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525943/is-the-mac-app-store-required)

But I still have a doubt. Basically what I want is to develop a simple app with some 3rd party frameworks in and then give it to a friend for normal usage.

Are there any restrictions in any regard? I have a free iOS and Mac developer account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. You do not need a Mac developer account at all. I would still suggest that you code-sign the app bundle though.

The only caveat is the user would needs to change a setting on their Mac to allow it through Gatekeeper.

[image: "Allow apps downloaded from : App Store and identified developers]